# Не отображаются виджеты в дочернем окне, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import settings

# Основное окно

root = Tk()
root.title("Рандомайзер")   # Название окна
root.geometry("800x500+150+200") # Размер окна
root.iconbitmap(settings.ICON) # Иконка окна
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна

C = Canvas(bg="blue", height=250, width=300) 
filename = PhotoImage(file=settings.BACKGROUND) # Фон окна
background_label = Label(image=filename)    
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 

fg = '#f0e6e8'  # Мягкий белый цвет     
bg = '#BA112C'  # Цвет фона


# Окно настроек
def create_window():
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TRadiobutton", background="#BA112C", foreground='white')
    second_window = Toplevel()     
    second_window.title("Настройки")     
    second_window.geometry("400x250+200+400") # Размер окна
    second_window.iconbitmap(settings.ICON_SETTINGS) # Иконка окна
    second_window.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна
    bg_settings_window = settings.BACKGROUND2
    img = PhotoImage(file=bg_settings_window)
    panel = Label(second_window, image=img)
    panel.pack()
    second_window.mainloop()

    # Button, Entry, Labels (window_settings)

    ttk.Radiobutton(second_window, value=1, style="TRadiobutton").pack()

# Logic window 1


# Button, Label, Entry 

# Все картинки

images = {
    'btn_generate': PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_GENERATE),
    'btn_icon': PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_ICON_SETTINGS),
}

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("TRadiobutton", background=bg, foreground='white')
style.configure("TButton", background=bg, foreground="#BA112C", font="HelveticaNeueCyr 17 bold", image=images['btn_generate'])

main_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=60, font="Arial 10 bold")
main_entry.place(x=190, y=150, height=55)

ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Выбрать из списка", value=1, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайное число", value=2, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайный пароль", value=3, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=390)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Перемешать слова", value=4, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=390)

ttk.Button(root, text="Сгенерировать", style="TButton").place(x=283, y=235)
Button(root, image=images['btn_icon'], background=bg, command=create_window).place(x=730, y=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Файл *settings* отвечает за путь к изображением (может у кого-то будут вопросы). Дочерние элементы, такие как, `RadioButton` не отображаются в дочернем окне, почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка вам "всё испортила":

```
second_window.mainloop()
```

Удалите её. Достаточно одного цикла обработки событий на весь `tkinter`, И вы его уже запустили как `root.mainloop()`.

[image: -]

Comment: убрал, запустил, в окне настройки вообще нет фона и радиокнопки

Comment: но когда добавляю mainloop() в конец, всё работает, точнее, только фон, а кнопки нет

Comment: Значит у вас в программе ещё какая-то логика, которую вы выкинули из примера. Если запустите ваш пример, и выкинете эту строчку, то увидите, что кнопка будет.

Comment: у меня там фон просто стоит, может фон всё закрывает? Тогда как это исправить?

Comment: куда вам папку с проектом скинуть?

Comment: я нашёл ошибку, это всё из-за лейбла, которого я отрисовываю как изображение. Попытался через канвас отрисовать, но фона нет